# Positioning UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I realise that this question has been asked a few times and I have followed the replies but it is not working for me.

I have a `UITableView`, included the following in the .h file:

```
@interface ObViewControllerPreObsInfo : UIViewController < UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and set the `delegate` and `dataSource` in viewDidLoad:

```
[tableViewNames setDelegate: self];
[tableViewNames setDataSource: self];
```

but when I try:

```
self.tableViewNames.frame.origin = 280;
```

I get the error

> Expression is not assignable

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a new frame and then assign it to the view. Try this:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableViewNames.frame;
frame.origin.x = 20;
frame.origin.y = 20;
self.tableViewNames.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CGRectMake`

```
self.tableViewNames.frame = CGRectMake(0, 310, 280,200);
```